# Do I have to reset Audio Session Properties after interruption?

Tags: ios, session, audio

I am implementing a C listener to Audio Session Interruption. When it is called for interruption, I would deactivate my audio session. Then when my app resumes, I would activate the audio session again. I have set a number of properties and category for my audio session, do I have to reset everything after re-activation?

Thanks in advance.

Some code for reference:

Initialization, setting category:

```
OSStatus error = AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, interuptListenerCallBack, (__bridge void *)(self));
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
error = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category);
if (error) printf("couldn't set audio category!");
//use speaker as default
UInt32 doChangeDefaultOutput = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefaultOutput), &doChangeDefaultOutput);
//allow bluethoothInput 
UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput, sizeof(allowBluetoothInput), &allowBluetoothInput);
```

The interuptListenerCallBack is where I deactivate and reactive the Audio Session because of the interruption, using

```
 OSStatus error = AudioSessionSetActive(false);
 if (error) printf("couldn't deactivate audio session!");
```

Or

```
  OSStatus error = AudioSessionSetActive(true);
  if (error) printf("AudioSessionSetActive (true) failed");
```

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Where is the code to initialize the player and start playing? What code interrupts it?

Comment: I've made an edit, please see if there's sufficient information?

Comment: That's enough. I gave an answer. +1 for making me do some research ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are correctly using the Audio session interruption listener, then no, you should not have to reset the properties. You just need to make sure that you actually call `kAudioSessionBeginInterruption` and `kAudioSessionEndInterruption`. I am not sure what your listener looks like, but if you are doing something like this:

```
if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption) {
        AudioSessionSetActive(NO);
    }
    if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption) {

        AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
    }
```

And are following the rules of Audio Session, Then theoretically, you should not have to reset your properties.

I don't know what you are using the Audio Session for, but you could also pause and resume playback by using the:

```
kAudioSessionInterruptionType_ShouldResume
```

and

```
kAudioSessionInterruptionType_ShouldNotResume.
```

You can use these as stated in the Docs:

> ```
> kAudioSessionInterruptionType_ShouldResume
> ```
>
> Indicates that the interruption that has just ended was one for
>   which it is appropriate to immediately resume playback; for example,
>   an incoming phone call was rejected by the user.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AudioSession.h.
>
> ```
> kAudioSessionInterruptionType_ShouldNotResume
> ```
>
> Indicates that the interruption that has just ended was one for which it is not appropriate to resume playback; for example, your app
>   had been interrupted by iPod playback.
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AudioSession.h.

You should read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Interruption_States) because there is a lot of info in there about pausing, resuming, and handling interruptions for the AudioSession.

**NOTE:**

AudioSession has been deprecated since iOS7. Use [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240-CH1-SW13) methods instead, or set Pause and Resume option by setting the constant [`AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions) or [`AVAudioSessionInterruptionType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AVAudioSessionInterruptionType).

(Available since iOS 6)

Comment: AudioSessionSetActive (BOOL) has been deprecated since iOS 7 . Use - (BOOL)setActive:(BOOL)beActive
            error:(NSError * _Nullable *)outError instead

Comment: Thanks, @MithunMadhav, edited. Feel free to add an another answer if you have one that uses non-deprecated methods.

Comment: Sure CaptJak , but i am currently in the middle of a related issue and will add an answer when i have solved it. My VoIP app is going mute even after the audio interruption ends :)